# LibSVM one class classification nu parameter is not a fraction of outliers?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

please correct me if I'm wrong, but the one class SVM theory states, that nu parameter is the upper bound (UB) of outliers in the training dataset and lower bound (LB) of number of SVs. Say I'm using RBF gaussian kernel, so by the idea of nu parameter, it does not matter what value of gamma I choose, the model should be able to produce results, such that the parameter nu is the UB of outliers in the training dataset? However, it's not what I've observed by trying out some simple example with LibSVM in Matlab:

```
[heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst] = libsvmread('../heart_scale');
ind_good = (heart_scale_label==1);
heart_scale_label = heart_scale_label(ind_good);
heart_scale_inst = heart_scale_inst(ind_good);
train_data = heart_scale_inst;
train_label = heart_scale_label;
gamma= 0.01;
nu=0.01;
model = svmtrain(train_label, train_data, ['-s 2 -t 2 -n ' num2str(nu) ' -g ' num2str(gamma) ' -h 0']);
[predict_label_Tr, accuracy_Tr, dec_values_Tr] = svmpredict(train_label, train_data, model);
accuracy_Tr
```

using gamma = 0.01 I get the accuracy of training data as 97.50
using gamma = 100 I get the accuracy of training data as 42.50
Shouldn't the model overfit to the data to get the same fraction of outliers in the training dataset, when larger gamma is selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I discovered the same problem. The performance of SVMs usually also depends on the interaction of γ and nu. If fixing one parameter while trying to tune another, the learning curve seems even not monotone.

I draw three images on the training accuracy, testing accuracy (5-fold on heart_scale data), and their difference. γ ranges from `10^(-4)` to `10^(1)`, and nu ranges from `10^(-3)` to `10^(-1)`:

[image]

To observe more clearly on the small parameters, I implemented the logarithm on the γ and nu axis, see the figure below:

[image]

Basically the underfit is much more evident than overfit with the given 120 data.

**EDIT**

Tune epsilon value to `1e-8` to fill the gap shown in the figure above:

[image]

No obvious overfitting or underfitting at all! Seems a little bit counter-intuitive as the dependence of generalization error upon the parameters, probably due to the optimization algorithm used in libsvm rather than the 'true' solution...

Comment: Do you have any idea why is SVM performing that way? I've noticed that when the results are not in line with nu parameter, the decision values of the model are usually small, of order 10^-5 or so. I have a thought that this might be happening due to a big stopping criteria of optimization algorithm if compared to the decision values. Have you tried to figure out why SVM is behaving like this?

Comment: Thank you MVil. You are making a very good point. Using the '-e' option, my result shows there is no under- or over-fitting when both parameters are small. I guess it's due to the SMO algorithms applied by libsvm. Note that libsvm optimization is pretty fast, so some approximations are expected to apply. If you are using something else to implement the svm (such as scikit learn), you may try to compare the result from both

Comment: Thank you for your time lennon310, I think it is ok to mark this question as answered. Unfortunately theoretical results sometimes stays theoretical because of some practical implementation issues. I think this is one of such cases. Thank you for your help once more.

Comment: you are very welcome. And thanks for accepting my answer. Also look forward to more interesting discoveries on svm (though most probably due to the software issue).

Comment: just to reconfirm, what we've been discussing about the possible computational errors, i've got an answer from authors of LibSVM software. They included this question to their FAQ section. http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f425

Comment: Thank you very much for your update. Actually the trend for nu seems OK compared with gamma. And as they said, yes it is probably due to the numerical errors that causes the hyperplane being overtuned. Thank you again for keeping me post.

Comment: Do you know why nu  is not allowed to get the value 0?